# How do I check if a browser supports the creation of a ClipBoardItem?

Tags: javascript, clipboard

I want to determine if a browser is able to create a `new ClipBoardItem` in Javascript.
The following if condition is sometimes true and sometimes false in Google Chrome so it doesn't work in my case:

```
if(typeof ClipBoardItem !== "undefined") {
    // new ClipBoardItem()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it ClipboardItem instead of ClipBoardItem, because typeof ClipboardItem is giving me correct results.